# Why Data Loader is not recommended to be used for uploading Knowledge Base Articles in Salesforce?

Tags: data-loader, knowledge, import, data-import-wizard, data-import

While being working with Salesforce since 2013, I have never digged much into Service Cloud functionality.

Now I have a task to migrate 4000 KB Articles into Salesforce KB and I wonder if I can achieve this goal using Dataloader or do I have to use some other tool?

Why can't I achieve this goal using simply Dataloader itself without using Import Articles wizard?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there are certain obstacles in using Dataloader to import Knowledge Articles.

1. Certain Data Loader versions (newer than 55.0) have certain issues with HTML rich-text area import.
2. Also it is really hard or almost impossible to import an article with images into Salesforce Knowledge base.

When you use Import Articles, the image links are processed by Salesforce and converted into link using the following format: `/servlet/rtaImage?eid={Knowledge article id}&feoid={field id}&refId={Content reference id}`.

This is not possible to obtain Knowledge Article Id before the article is created (but this may be overcome with insert and consequent update operation).

Also it is not possible to get the Content Reference Id, this object cannot be queried and neither ContentVersion, nor ContentDocument has a link to it.

So there is currently no way to mimic the `Import Articles` functionality using Data Loader.

Probably we could replace the image links with `<img src="/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/<contentVersionId>" />` link, however, this won't be the same exact and uploading knowledge articles using `Import Articles` functionality, since uploaded image files won't be shared automatically with all necessary users.

So looks like `Import Articles` functionality is the only option to Import Knowledge Articles into Salesforce and there are no workarounds or hacks to make it easier unless there are no images or content to be loaded within the articles.

Comment: Try [SFDMU](https://help.sfdmu.com/). Haven't tried it with Knowledge but should work.